# let a rpm to automatically install centos-release-scl-rh

Tags: rpm, yum, rpm-spec

I have created a rpm on Centos 7
it needs rh-python36 
and centos-release-scl-rh is required to be installed in advance,
so the current sequence is :

```
sudo yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh
sudo yum -y  localinstall ~/my_rpm.rpm
```

I would like to automatically install centos-release-scl-rh
I tried to add it to the 'Requires' but it didn't work
at the current stage I have to install centos-release-scl-rh in advance.

any suggestions ?

Comment: suggestion is to delete here and repost to https://unix.stackexchange.com . Please read the [help on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

inside your spec file you need to put that my_rpm **requires** centos-release-scl-rh :

```
Requires: centos-release-scl-rh
```

then this will be installed before my_rpm.rpm can be installed.

Comment: while you're at it; you probably want to add `Requires: rh-python36` or similar (make sure you get the package name correctly)

Comment: I tried it : 

Requires:      centos-release-scl-rh, rh-python36


but it seems it is not able to manage rh-python36 unless I install centos-release-scl-rh in advance : 
```
Error: Package: foglamp-1.5.2-0.00.x86_64 (/foglamp-1.5.2-0.00.x86_64)
           Requires: rh-python36
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Comment: because the package `rh-python36` does not exist as such... how do you install it normally?

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. You *might* need a `README` or something telling the user to install `epel-release` first.

Comment: at @Chris Maes - the rh-python36 is in the  Requires but it is visible/installable only if I install centos-release-scl-rh in advace

Comment: oh that is a more complicated problem... you could give this a shot (not sure it is going to work): `Requires(pre): centos-release-scl-rh
Requires: rh-python36`

Comment: @ChrisMaes that won't work because it won't be able to resolve; that's now how `pre` works, sadly. There is no way to do it without having the repo in place beforehand.